# Impact of missing real-time clock on linux services (esp. asterisk)

Tags: linux, clock, asterisk

We're currently working on a new server, for an avionics system.

This server normally uses Debian Stretch. But the hardware we use has no battery to save the clock. After reboot, the factory date/time is restored. The server will probably not be connected to any NTP server over the internet.

I was wondering if it could cause some dysfunctions with services or kernel apps?

Furthermore, a version of this server might use the ASTERISK framework to provide onflight telephony services. Again, I was wondering if this could become a blocking issue ?

I'm not competent enough in the matter to figure out a potential impact.

Comment: 1) Some server PCs have a supercapacitor to keep the real time clock going instead of a battery. Do you mean to say there is _nothing_ to keep the real time clock of the server going? 2) Will there be an NTP server elsewhere in the avionics of the destination aircraft?

Comment: Debian 9 uses systemd 232, and "factory date/time" is not quite the right description for what systemd has done since version 229.

Comment: I am guessing that the server will have no internet connection at all. Am I right? Besides, is a writeable filesystem available on the server? If so, is it ext3 or xfs or something else?

Comment: @AndersonMedeirosGomes Yes. No internet connection. The filesystem remains writable. And it's an ext3 filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Debian Linux is not dependent on time accuracy for its own servers, kernel, and apps, but I would manually enter a time after booting if no time source server is available.

However, communications with other servers may well require it, but you've only mentioned [asterisk](https://community.asterisk.org/search?q=NTP). The asterisk server can also be running an ntp service to meet the connectivity requirements of telephony services it connects to.

Comment: I'd be thinking about superblock timestamps, systemd journal timestamps, and `multilog`/`cyclog` filenames and line timestamps at this point; even disregarding encryption and billing in any telephony.

Comment: Those will be internally consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that an inaccurate clock will not be an issue for the kernel and applications running on server. However, some applications and services may present issues if they detect a clock shifted backwards. For example:

- EXT2/3/4 filesystems trigger forced file system checks if they detect that either the last mount time or last write time is beyond the current time ([workaround here](https://serverfault.com/q/378846)).
- Logrotate will not be able to rotate and purge old log files from `/var/log`.
- Applications relying on locally-generated x509 certificates for mutual authentication may stop working due to validity start dates set to the future.

Your server has a writeable file system. So a viable approach for the system is to prevent the clock from going backwards by storing the clock on it. The [`fake-hwclock` package](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/fake-hwclock) comes handy for such demand:

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get -y install fake-hwclock
# fake-hwclock save
```